# C# SOAP Web Services client - example that shows how to log all raw SOAP intput and output?

Tags: c#, web-services, logging, soap

I'm looking for a C# example showing how to access a remote SOAP Web Service, and logging (to a file, or even just to a string I can do whatever with) all complete raw SOAP requests and complete raw SOAP responses.

I found some other posts on StackOverflow with similar topics, but they seem to reference a web.config file, which my *desktop* application does not have. I assume this is because they are using C# in the form of a web application querying a remote SOAP web service. Mine is a desktop application.

Any takers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [SOAP extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk%28VS.71%29.aspx) to get the SOAP content as a string and then log it wherever.

Answer (score 2):

In the above post, that should be "app.config" and "web.config", and the better URL is the one at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493883/silverlight-wcf-problem-expecting-application-soapxml-received-text-xml/493931#493931) for info on WCF logging.  You can log to a file, and there is a special viewer to make reading the logs easy.

Your windows configuration file is named app.config rather than web.config and lives in the bin folder alongside the exe file.  Within Visual Studio there is a "top level" AppConfig file that VS copies to the bin folder when you compile.  You may need to add the AppConfig file to your project -- it is a special file type in the Add Item dialog.

+tom